# How can I sort by word/token in Excel 2011 

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2011

Is it possible to sort a spreadsheet based on if a word is contained in cells within a column?

Like if I take the "title" column and sort, keeping the rows connected, to bring all the rows with a certain word to the top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am gonna go ahead and answer this for posterity's sake.  what you wanna do here, bboy, is highlight your column and look for the 'conditional formatting' box, it is a bit harder in older editions, but 2011 is proper quick with a button under your 'home' workspace.
so you hit 'conditional formatting' with your column highlighted and 2011 gives you a dialog box that allows you to highlight based on 'text contains...' insert your text and all the cells with that token will change color.
you can then go to 'data' and 'sort' , sort the entire sheet based on the appropriate column based on 'cell color' instead of 'value'.
this will give you the effect you are looking for, older versions need to use a function applied to the whole column something like =stringcontains(text), not that exactly but its logical equivalent.
hope this helps and you havent found a way to travel into the future, learn the answer, post the answer, travel back in time, and read the answer with no knowledge of said time-travel